# Incremental Loading catch and throw exception Metro App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Currently i am developing metro app that has a `GridView` which populates data on scrolling. For that purpose i have to implement `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface. I have done this and my code is working fine. But i want to know how to throw `Exception` from `LoadMoreItemsAsync` function if exception occurs. Below is the code snippet.

```
public Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        if (count > 50 || count <= 0)
        {
            // default load count to be set to 50
            count = 50;
        }

        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(
            async () =>
            {

                List<MovieInfo> result = new List<MovieInfo>();

                try
                {
                    result = await ytSearcher.SearchVideos(Query, ++CurrentPage);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    // here i want to throw that exception.  
                }

                await this.dispatcher.RunAsync(
                    CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    () =>
                    {
                        foreach (MovieInfo item in result)
                            this.Add(item);
                    });

                return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = (uint)result.Count() };

            }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that experient in the Windows Runtime but, I would refactor your code to something like this:

```
public Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
{
    if (count > 50 || count <= 0)
    {
        // default load count to be set to 50
        count = 50;
    }

    return LoadMoreItemsTaskAsync(count)
        .AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
}

private async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsTaskAsync(uint count)
{
    var result = await ytSearcher.SearchVideos(Query, ++CurrentPage);

    result.ForEach(i => this.Add(i));

    return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = (uint)result.Count };
}
```

Beware that `List<T>` has a `Count` property with the number of items in the list while the `Count` methtod is a `LINQ` extension method that iterates through all items to compute the number of items.

Of course this doesn't answer your question, but with this much more cleaner code you might more easily figure it out or get help figuring it out.